# printing jframe in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

How to print the content of `JFrame`?

Comment: Print to the screen, stdout or to a printer?

Comment: Oohh JFrame to AsciiArt converter, that would be fun.

Comment: This link provides exactly what you are looking for with additional useful tips http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html

Answer (score 2):

```
     PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setPrintable(this);
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok)
        {
            try
            {
              job.print();
            }
            catch (PrinterException ex)
            {
            /* The job did not successfully complete */
            }
        }

       public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Now print the window and its visible contents */
    jFrame.paint(g2d);
    jFrame.repaint();
    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```